# Creating a Multidimensional, Associative Array in VBScript

Tags: vbscript, multidimensional-array, associative-array

Is it possible to create a multidimensional, associative array in VBScript?

I'm trying to recreate the following JScript code in VBScript:

```
names["teachers"] = ["Helen","Judy","Carol"];
names["students"] = ["George","John","Katie"];

For (var i=0; i<names["teachers"].length; i++) {

     Response.Write(names["teachers"][i]);

}
```

My attempted VBScript:

```
dim names

SET names = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

names.Add "teachers", Array("Helen","Judy","Carol")
names.Add "students", Array("George","John","Katie")
```

There doesn't seem to be an error creating the object, but I'm unable to figure out how I can loop through the arrays in VBScript.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's no real trick to iterating through this data structure. You do it just how you would expect to.

```
For Each key In names
    For i = 0 To UBound(names(key))
        WScript.Echo "names(" & key & ")(" & i & ") = " & names(key)(i)
    Next
Next
```