# VBS multidimensional array from a For Each

Tags: multidimensional-array, vbscript

Perspective: This script will run on user login and on command with a shortcut on the desktop.  The order the application start is imperative.  Throughout the script, I require the full path and the program name.

Problem: Each program path is a value in an array. I am trying to split each program path by “\” and get the upper bound to get the program name. Then Redim Preserve the original array and add the program on the second dimension. After reading for many hours, I grasp I can only change the last dimension, but I can’t figure out how to not get out of bound errors. This [Creating a Multidimensional, Associative Array in VBScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4588469/creating-a-multidimensional-associative-array-in-vbscript) is not trying to redim preserve from a For Each split.

```
Set objFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'---Create Program Variables
strProgram1 = "%SystemRoot%\notepad.exe" 
strProgram2 = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\OUTLOOK.EXE" 
strProgram3 = "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\ONENOTE.EXE" 
strProgram4 = "C:\Program Files (x86)\Internet Explorer\iexplore.exe" & " https://www.google.com" 'IE with URL

'---Add Program Path Variables to an Array
ReDim strProgramList(3) 
strProgramList = Array(strProgram1,strProgram2,strProgram3,strProgram4)

strProgramNameList = Array()
strProgramRestartList = Array()
boolNeedsRestart = false

'---Iterating using For each loop to get program name. 
ReDim Preserve strProgramList(3, 1)
For Each strProgramPath In strProgramList
        strPathComponents = Split(strProgramPath, "\")
        strProgramName = strPathComponents(Ubound(strPathComponents))
        strProgramList(0, LBound(strProgramList) + 1) = strProgramName

Next

MsgBox strProgramList(0,0) & vbNewLine & strProgramList(1,0) & vbNewLine & strProgramList(2,0)  & vbNewLine & strProgramList(3,0) & vbNewLine & strProgramList(0,1) & vbNewLine & strProgramList(1,1) & vbNewLine & strProgramList(2,1) & vbNewLine & strProgramList(3,1)
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a Multidimensional, Associative Array in VBScript](//stackoverflow.com/q/4588469)

Answer (score 1):

How to use the FileSystemObject to parse/build pathes and how to work with two-dimensional [arrays](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t7zd6etz(v=vs.84).aspx#Array%20Variables):

```
Option Explicit

Dim goFS : Set goFS = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Dim a    : a        = Split("A:\B\CC.EXE A:\CC\DD.CMD C:\You\Got\It.pl")
ReDim b(2, UBound(a))
Dim i
For i = 0 To UBound(a)
   b(0, i) = a(i)
   b(1, i) = goFS.GetParentFolderName(a(i))
   b(2, i) = goFS.GetFileName(a(i))
Next
ReDim Preserve b(2, UBound(b, 2) + 1)
b(0, UBound(b, 2)) = "P:\i\pa\po.py"
b(1, UBound(b, 2)) = goFS.GetParentFolderName(b(0, UBound(b, 2)))
b(2, UBound(b, 2)) = goFS.GetFileName(b(0, UBound(b, 2)))
For i = 0 To UBound(b, 2)
   WScript.Echo b(0, i), "=", b(1, i), "+", b(2, i), "=>", goFS.BuildPath(b(1, i), b(2, i))
Next
```

output:

```
cscript twodim.vbs
A:\B\CC.EXE = A:\B + CC.EXE => A:\B\CC.EXE
A:\CC\DD.CMD = A:\CC + DD.CMD => A:\CC\DD.CMD
C:\You\Got\It.pl = C:\You\Got + It.pl => C:\You\Got\It.pl
P:\i\pa\po.py = P:\i\pa + po.py => P:\i\pa\po.py
```

Comment: What about explaining the code instead for us lesser mortals?

Comment: Horner, I think you have correctly understood my intentions. 
I replaced your file paths initially with my strProgramList to set it as “a.” I received the error “type mismatch.” I then changed it to strProgramList(1) just to see if I have any idea of what is going on. This time your code ran, obviously only the first program, however it is splitting on the spaces. I tried changing it to this     Dim a    : a        = Split(strProgramList(1), "\") but that did not work.  
Thanks

Comment: @user2847926 it's not a case of correctly understanding your intentions, it's about providing a detailed enough answer to help others who might have a similar issue. This question is a clear duplicate anyway, we are not here to fix the minor nuances of your code.